# Load Categorywith id in bootstrap.php Shopware 5

Tags: dbal, shopware

in my bootstrap.php I try to load a category with a special id.
Its not quite working.

```
    public function getCatFromDb($idCat){
    /** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $connection */
    $connection = $connection->get('dbal_connection');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM s_categories WHERE id=$idCat';
    $result = $connection->query($sql)->fetch();
    var_dump($result);

    return $result;
}
```

Can someone spot the mistake?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Figured out the mistake.
Put
$connection = $container->get('dbal_connection');
and
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM s_categories WHERE id="$idCat"';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `ModelManager` to retrieve the `Category`.

```
/** @var ModelManager $modelManager */
$modelManager = Shopware()->Container()->get('models');
// you could use this, too
// $modelManager = $this->container->get('models');
/** @var Category $category */
$category = $modelManager->getRepository(Category::class)->find($id);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$connection = $container->get('dbal_connection');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM s_categories WHERE id="$idCat"';
```

Container instead the second connection, and $idCat in  quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getCatFromDb($idCat){
    /** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $connection */
    //$connection = Shopware()->Container()->get('dbal_connection');
    $connection = $connection->get('dbal_connection');
    $result = $connection->executeQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM s_categories WHERE id=?", [$idCat]
    )->fetchAll();
    var_dump($result);

    return $result;
}
```